# CPT's archive and single page not working

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I created a custom post type

```
function faq_func() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'FAQs', 'Post Type General Name', 'rrrrr' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'FAQ', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'rrrrr' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'FAQ', 'rrrrr' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'rrrrr' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'rrrrr' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Items', 'rrrrr' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New', 'rrrrr' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'New Item', 'rrrrr' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'rrrrr' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'rrrrr' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'rrrrr' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'No items found', 'rrrrr' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No items found in Trash', 'rrrrr' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'faq',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => false,
    'feeds'               => false,
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'faqs', 'rrrrr' ),
    'description'         => __( 'FAQ Page', 'rrrrr' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/faq-icon.png',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'query_var'           => 'faq',
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'faqs', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'faq_func', 0 );
```

And a archive-faqs.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'faqs' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The problem is that my items not visible on the page. Where is the problem?

UPDATE: I found the solution on wordpress.org:

Note: In some cases, the permalink structure must be updated in order for the new template files to be accessed when viewing posts of a custom post type. To do this, go to Administration Panels > Settings > Permalinks, change the permalink structure to a different structure, save the changes, and change it back to the desired structure.

Comment: Your title implies that the CPT single/archive template files aren't being *used*, but in your question you indicate that the problem is that *terms aren't being displayed*. Which is it? And if the problem is that terms aren't being displayed, you'll need to include the template code that you expect to output those terms.

Comment: Also: why are you creating a custom query loop in `archive-faqs.php`?

Comment: I would like to list only the content and the title what I add under the FAQ cpt. I don't use terms/taxonomies. I replaced the query `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('No posts were found. Sorry!'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>`

with this but it's not working.

Comment: That's fine. The issue is this: `$loop = new WP_Query( $args );`. Why are you doing that? It essentially stomps on the default WordPress query - which is ostensibly the very query you want to loop through/output.

Comment: I copied that from wordpress.org. Now I'm using the default query in the archive-faqs.php but it's not working.

Comment: +1 for finding your own solution. Post it as an answer rather than an update, so you can mark this solved in 2 days. Any time you add a taxonomy/post type, you have to refresh the permalinks by doing exactly what you did. Otherwise, that content will not appear.

Comment: Thank you Eric!

**I found the solution on wordpress.org:**

Note: In some cases, the permalink structure must be updated in order for the new template files to be accessed when viewing posts of a custom post type. To do this, go to Administration Panels > Settings > Permalinks, change the permalink structure to a different structure, save the changes, and change it back to the desired structure.